# PHP array for loop

Tags: php

I want to show the array value `$result[]` from the `for` loop calculation. However, it shows me nothing on the page. Is there is anything wrong in the below code?

```
$sql= "SELECT * FROM items where itemID =3 ";
$result1= mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
while ($row= mysql_fetch_array($result1)){

    $quantity[] = $row ['quantity'];

    $month[] = $row ['month'];
}

$alpha = 0.3;

for($i = 1; $i > 12; $i++){

    $result[$i] = ($quantity[$i] - $result[$i-1]) * $alpha + $result[$i-1];

}

foreach ($result as $key => $value ){

 echo "$value";

}
```

Comment: I hate to ask, but is `$result` initialized?

Comment: itemId looks like the primary key. If this is the case, you do not need the first `while` nor arrays.

Comment: the `$i > 12` condition is never met. I think you wanted to use `$i < 12` or `$i <= 12`.

Comment: Also, in this case, I think you should use mysql_fetch_assoc instead of mysql_fetch_array

Comment: Order of records in db is not preserved. How can you be sure that your select gives you months in correct order and your calculation will be valid? IMHO you need to use `ORDER BY`

Answer (score 7):

Your for loop has an error. You have

```
for($i = 1; $i > 12; $i++)
```

but it should be

```
for($i = 1; $i < 12; $i++)
```

Comment: Haha! I was typing this exact same thing!

Comment: Read through the code, didn't pick it up. It was only as I was scrolling past and not really looking that I saw it.

Comment: While we're here, let's learn something. What does PHP do when it sees something like that? Shrug in disgust and move on? Generate a warning?

Comment: @L_Holcombe While it is an incorrect loop constructor it is essentially valid by PHP's standards, so it will set `$i` to the value `1`, test if `$i > 12`, conclude that it isn't and silently bypass the for loop.

Answer (score 1):

**This is not directly the answer to your question**, but there are few things that hasn't been mentioned that concern the way you query and process your data:

1. Your `SELECT` statement doesn't have specific order specified. Since order of records is not preserved you can get records out of correct order and get invalid calculations. Use `ORDER BY` (e.g. `ORDER BY month`) or make use of month values and extract exactly previous month's value from array(s) (if it is what you're doing in your code).
2. Your current code relies on the fact that the resultset from DB will contain (at least) 12 records. If for some reason it will produce less records your `for` loop will brake.
3. It's uncertain from the information in the question but it looks like you might need a year in your query unless the table contains records only for one year.

Now, you can calculate the whole thing on DB side with a query like this

```sql
SELECT i.month, 
       COALESCE((i.quantity - p.quantity) * 0.3 + p.quantity, 0) value
  FROM items i LEFT JOIN items p
    ON i.itemID = p.itemID
   AND i.`year` = p.`year`
   AND i.month = p.month + 1
 WHERE i.itemID = 3
   AND i.`year` = 2013
 ORDER BY month
```

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3c23d7/1)**

*That's assuming (and I'm not sure about that) you actually need to read previous month's quantity values for your calculations and `month` column is of integer type*

Answer (score 0):

There is an obvious flaw in the logic. You try to get the $i index form $quantity. However, you can't be sure $quantity will have this index.
Supposing that itemId is not the primary key, I would do something like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `items` WHERE `itemID` = 3";
$result1= mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
while ($row= mysql_fetch_assoc($result1)){    
    $quantity[] = $row ['quantity'];
}

$alpha = 0.3;

$i = 1
foreach ($quantity as $elem) {
    if ($i >= 12)
      break;
    $result[$i] = ($elem - $result[$i-1]) * $alpha + $result[$i-1]; 
    $i++
}

foreach ($result as $value ){
 echo $value;
}
```